# How to dispose ILogger Scope created by Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, dispose

I have have defined a logger Scope in the DI class

```
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
var logger =  serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Processor>>();

logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"system", "MyApplication"},
    {"invocation_id", Guid.NewGuid()}
});
```

The Logger is used like this (works fine)

```
public class Processor : IProcessor
{
    private readonly ILogger<Processor> logger;

    public Processor(ILogger<Processor> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void LogMessage()
    {
        logger.LogInformation(""Hello World");
        //Dispose Logger
    }
}
```

How do i dispose of this logger once completed?

Comment: The rule with disposable objects is that "he who creates the disposable, should dispose of it". So this typically means that the same class that creates the logger scope, should also dispose of it.

Answer (score 1):

`BeginScope` returns an IDisposable, that closes the logging scope.
Normally I would wrap my operation inside the a using statement.

```
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
var logger =  serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Processor>>();

using (logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"system", "MyApplication"},
    {"invocation_id", Guid.NewGuid()}
})) 
{
    IProcessor processor = new Processor(logger);
    ... do your thing
}
```

This is similar to the recommendations from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-scopes